# Powershell: Properly escape apostrophes

Tags: powershell, plink

I want to execute a command from powershell, which in turn executes a command on a foreign server, using `plink`. But this only works if I do not have `'` or `"` in the command, otherwise Powershell jumps in and prints exceptions.

Example:

```
Invoke-Expression "$plinkPath -ssh $username@$host 'echo well...; echo hello'"
```

gives

```
well...
hello
```

. But what if I want to echo both `'` and `"`, say

```
Invoke-Expression "$plinkPath -ssh $username@$host 'echo well...; echo hello, my "friend" 'brutus'!'"
```

to get

```
well...
hello, my "friend" 'brutus'!
```

?

Edit: Extension, I want to have a `$`.

```
well...
hello, my "friend" 'brutus', you $insult!
```

Comment: Try escaping with the backtick so (`) which is the same key as the tilde (~) on the keyboard. Or actually try doubling up the single quotes as well. Read here for details that you may find helpful as well: http://www.rlmueller.net/PowerShellEscape.htm

Comment: You're using the wrong cmdlet to do the job. [`Invoke-Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Invoke-Expression) should be used to execute a local command (PowerShell code). If you do want to run an executable just do so. Maybe consider using one of options listed in [How to run an EXE file in PowerShell with parameters with spaces and quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673967/how-to-run-an-exe-file-in-powershell-with-parameters-with-spaces-and-quotes)

Comment: While both of your suggestions are fine, it got way to cluttered for me when it comes to running `awk` with its (even for itself) almost unreadable command lines. So I ended up packing the commands into a script and uploading that with `pscp` and running it with `plink`.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, this is the command for the response I asked for:

```
& $plinkPath -ssh $username@$host "echo well...; echo Hello, my \\\`"friend\\\`" \'brutus\', you \`$insult!"
```

It brings

```
well...
Hello, my "friend" 'brutus', you $insult!
```