# Properly escape awk command from powershell over plink

Tags: linux, powershell, plink

After ([Powershell: Properly escape apostrophes](https://superuser.com/questions/1226229/powershell-properly-escape-apostrophes)) I still haven't figured out how to get those escapes right when executing a command over plink, coming from powershell.

What I am trying to execute at the linux host, is

```
df -k / | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}'
```

This just gives me the amount of free KB at `/`.

Since I am at my powershell (Windows), I have to build a `plink` command to get the command to the server. Naively, it looks like this:

```
& plink -ssh -l $user -batch -pw $pw $user@$IP df -k / | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}'
```

**This fails**, because PowerShell jumps in at the `|` and searches for a command `tail`. So, I have to  escape the pipes like that:

```
& plink -ssh -l $user -batch -pw $pw $user@$IP df -k / `| tail -1 `| awk '{print $4}'
```

This gives me `awk: cmd. line:1: Unexpected end of string`.

I think, I have to escape the `$4` twice, because PowerShell *and* the Linux Bash try to replace it with a variable. But how can I do that? 
Using

```
\`$4
```

doesn't change the message.

Comment: Try ``plink -ssh -l $user -batch -pw $pw $user@$IP "df -k / | tail -1 | awk '{print `$4}'"``

Comment: Yeees, that works! If you post it as an answer, I can accept it. :) Perhaps you could add a hint on what to do if the awk command contained `"` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `` plink -ssh -l $user -batch -pw $pw $user@$IP "df -k / | tail -1 | awk '{print `$4}'" ``.

## Powershell escaping in general:

### Escaping characters between two double quotes:

- `$` needs to be escaped with `` `$ ``
- `"` needs to be escaped with `` `" ``
- `` ` `` needs to be escaped with ``` `` ```

**Exception:**
A trailing (at the end of the double quote) `$` doesn't need to be escaped at all.

### Escaping characters between two single quotes:

- `'` needs to be escaped with `''`

### Escaping characters not enclosed by quotes:

- `$` needs to be escaped with `` `$ ``
- `@` needs to be escaped with `` `@ ``
- `#` needs to be escaped with `` `# ``
- `` ` `` needs to be escaped with ``` `` ```
- `|` needs to be escaped with `` `| ``
- `{` and `}` need to be escaped with `` `{ `` and `` `} ``
- `;` needs to be escaped with `` `; ``
- `"` needs to be escaped with `` `" ``
- `'` needs to be escaped with `` `' ``

**Exception:**
A trailing (at the end of the double quote) `$` doesn't need to be escaped at all.

### Special always escaped characters:

- `` `0 ``: Null-Character
- `` `a ``: Alert-Character
- `` `b ``: Backspace-Character
- `` `f ``: Form-Feed-Character
- `` `n ``: New-Line-Character
- `` `r ``: Carriage-Return-Character
- `` `t ``: Horizontal-Tab-Character
- `` `v ``: Vertical-Tab-Character

### Special ways to stop parsing special characters:

- Since Powershell 2.0 you can use `@' ... '@` to prevent the interpretation of your parameters, but `@'` needs to be in the same line as your command, the parameters need to be in the next line and `'@` needs to be in it's own line after the parameters
- Since Powershell 3.0 you can use `--%` to stop parsing everything after `--%`

### Example:

**`` $h@h#h`h|h{h}h;h"h'h$ ``:**

- Enclosed by double quotes: ``` exampleprogram.exe "`$h@h#h``h|h{h}h;h`"h'h$" ```
- Enclosed by single quotes: `` exampleprogram.exe '$h@h#h`h|h{h}h;h"h''h'$ ``
- Not enclosed by quotes: ``` exampleprogram.exe `$h`@h`#h``h`|h`{h`}h`;h`"h`'h$ ```
- Using `@' ... '@`:

> exampleprogram.exe @'
>   $h@h#h`h|h{h}h;h"h'h$
>   '@

- Using `--%`: `` exampleprogram.exe --% $h@h#h`h|h{h}h;h"h'h$ ``

Comment: Woooow. :-)) Will definitely bookmark this answer and wish I could upvote more than once.